# JavaScript: best practices implementation of the setInverval function

Tags: javascript

I want to log some text to the console every *n* number of seconds.  My code is:

```
function logger() {
    console.log("log some stuff...");
}
setInterval(logger, 3000);
```

This works fine.  And, the following variation works fine, too:

```
setInterval(
    function logger() {
    console.log("log some stuff...";
}, 3000);
```

Now, I attempt to move `setInterval` ***inside*** the function, as follows:

```
function logger() {
    console.log("log some stuff...");
    setInterval(logger, 3000);   // moving setInterval here does NOT work
}
```

This does not work.

Question:  Is there a way to move `setInverval` ***inside*** the function?  And, if it *is* possible, is doing so recommended?

Thanks for helping out a JavaScript newbie!

**### EDIT ###**

Taking the suggestion from @FZs, I implemented the function as follows:

```
function logger(output, interval) {
    var now = new Date()
    setInterval(function() {
        console.log(output, now.toLocaleString());
    }, interval)
}

logger("Foo ", 3000)
```

The messages are stacking in the console because the Date is not incrementing.  Is this a scope issue?

Comment: You never called it! Do `logger()` on the outside

Comment: @MrMythical and then soon after, the browser will crash.

Comment: No and no, it's neither possible nor recommended. Why would you want to do that?

Comment: Yes, they add a new interval every time

Comment: It will cause a recursion which will lead to a browser crash. Each time logger() is called, it will set and start a new interval and this calling grows exponentially, at last causing browser crash.

Comment: @Bergi -- I'm not suggesting that I WANT to do it.  I'm questioning whether I SHOULD do it? (i.e. whether doing so would be best practice)

Comment: @equanimity this will cause problems as they described. The browser will crash. So no, you shouldn't do it

Comment: `setTimeout` probably accomplishes what ya want - else intervals will just keep being created.

Comment: in the first example, you are passing `reference` to `logger function`.
in second, you are directly creating logger function inside, which will create a longer function every time interval is completed.

**But don't try 3rd example.**

Comment: @Himanshu Singh -- would the first example be considered the optimal implementation when one wants to log something at a set time interval?

Comment: AFAIK, I would say yes, because in second method each time `a new function is created every time the code that uses it runs, which in some cases makes no difference at all, but in other cases may be something to consider for performance reasons (e.g., if doing things in a loop or in setIntervals or setTImeout).`

Can read more about it at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9123896/what-are-the-advantages-and-disadvantages-of-anonymous-methods-in-javascript

Comment: Also, it would be interesting to understand why I was downvoted.  I believe the question met the standards for reproducibility, research, a suggested attempt at a solution, etc.

Comment: actually using setInterval is kinda bad Practice!

Comment: @vahid ghadiri -- providing a REASON might actually benefit the community.

Comment: If what you wanted is just having a function that makes an interval, you could create a wrapper function for your first or second code: `function logger(){ setInterval(function(){ console.log("log some stuff..."); }, 3000) }`. This way, you can call `logger()` and have a single interval.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved as follows:

```
function logger(output, interval) {

setInterval(function() {
    var now = new Date()  // moved this line here!
    console.log(output, now.toLocaleString());
}, interval)
}

logger("Foo ", 3000)
```